# Download a file with DefaultHTTPClient and preemptive authentication

Tags: android, file, authentication, download, preemptive

After I had a lot of problems with preemptive authentication , I got it finally working.
Now the next problem. I want to get a file with it, but I don't know how.
I thought the file data might be in the variable response, but it isn't.
Any ideas how this might work? I'm trying it since days without success :( - Basically I'm trying to download an jpeg file, which is on a server protected by prem. auth.

```
        // BASIC AUTH
        /*
         * ====================================================================
         *
         *  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
         *  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
         *  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
         *  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
         *  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
         *  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
         *
         *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
         *
         *  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
         *  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
         *  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
         *  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
         *  limitations under the License.
         * ====================================================================
         *
         * This software consists of voluntary contributions made by many
         * individuals on behalf of the Apache Software Foundation.  For more
         * information on the Apache Software Foundation, please see
         * <http://www.apache.org/>.
         */
        //http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/branches/4.0.x/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientPreemptiveBasicAuthentication.java
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                new AuthScope(host, port), 
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));

        // Generate BASIC scheme object and stick it to the local 
        // execution context
        BasicHttpContext localcontext = new BasicHttpContext();

        BasicScheme basicAuth = new BasicScheme();
        localcontext.setAttribute("preemptive-auth", basicAuth);

        //first request interceptor
        httpclient.addRequestInterceptor(new PreemptiveAuth(), 0);

       HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost(host, port, "http"); 

        //HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("/");

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(http.url); 

        System.out.println("executing request" + httpget.getRequestLine());
        /// !!!
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(targetHost, httpget, localcontext);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("+"+response.getStatusLine()+"+");
...
```

Comment: Does the server respond with the url of the image to be downloaded?

Comment: No, I'm using directly the URL e.g. http://123.123.123.123/admin/snapshot.jpg and opened in a browser the image is displayed. I need to know how to get the content of the file (which is definied in http.url), but for now I can find in response-variable only the headers, which the server is sending (HTTP 1.1 200 OK ... and so on) ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I solved it myself now - here the solution:

```
        StringBuffer tmp = new StringBuffer();  // for content

        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();

            int l = 0;
            byte[] t = new byte[1024];

            while ((l = is.read(t)) != -1) {
                for (int i=0; i<l ; i++){
                    tmp.append((char)t[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        return tmp.toString();
```