# Java IO cannot find existing file from URL

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I have a weird problem, i have to parse XML file to get data, when I parse file:
http://www.nbp.pl/kursy/xml/c073z070413.xml, all works ok (file is parsed), but when I try parse file : http://www.nbp.pl/kursy/xml/a002z020103.xml then I get a message that program cant find this file (In browser, the XML file works)

Exception:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Projects\AreYouSmart\abch.dtd (Could not found file)

Below is a full example code.
(Code is taken from [StackOverflow: XML parse file from HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058434/xml-parse-file-from-http))

```
public class TylkoPobieranie {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new TylkoPobieranie().start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void start() throws Exception {
        // link work: URL url = new URL("http://www.nbp.pl/kursy/xml/c073z070413.xml");
        URL url = new URL("http://www.nbp.pl/kursy/xml/a002z020103.xml");
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

        Document doc = parseXML(connection.getInputStream());
        NodeList descNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("pozycja");

        for (int i = 0; i < descNodes.getLength(); i++) {
            System.out.println(descNodes.item(i).getTextContent());
        }
    }

    private Document parseXML(InputStream stream) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory objDocumentBuilderFactory = null;
        DocumentBuilder objDocumentBuilder = null;
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            objDocumentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            //ANSWER:
             objDocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);

            objDocumentBuilder = objDocumentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            doc = objDocumentBuilder.parse(stream);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        }

        return doc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the start of each XML file - it looks to me like the second file refers to a DTD that can not be found on your machine ( C:\Projects\AreYouSmart\abch.dtd ) - Incidentally, I can't open the second file from my browser

Comment: You could have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155101/make-documentbuilder-parse-ignore-dtd-references to see how you can ignore the DTD in the second file

Comment: @DaveHowes I'll add to your comments that the reference to the DTD is on a002z020103.xml file (line two) I'll delete my answer as you found the problem first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That XML file has the line:

```
<!DOCTYPE tabela_kursow SYSTEM "abch.dtd">
```

It is the abch.dtd file that it cannot find.

Try this:

```
objDocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
```

Comment: How to skip this line?

Answer (score 1):

By default, Xerces (the built-in XML parser in Java) will try to load an external DTD file even if the parser is non-validating.

Calling `setValidating(false)` has no effect since it is already non-validating by default to start with. You can turn off external DTD loading after constructing the factory:

```
objDocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", 
                                     false);
```